# iOS tableview cell server sync timing

Tags: ios, database, uitableview, networking

I'm developing network base app.

There is database model A (e.g. contact), which is displayed by tableView.

User has local databse (e.g. realm) in the client and server receive the data when user signup this app. The record of model A is modified by the button in the tableViewCell. (e.g. change group of contact or add user tags of that contact)
The data modification is up to only user. Server-side can not modify the model A, only read the model A.
Ok. Here is the question. When the user open the table view and modify the record of model A, server-side record need to be updated. Then, what timing should I write the server request code? There could be several scenario.

1. At the touchupinside event of the button in the tableViewCell, dispatch asynchronous thread and request server to update the item using this REST API : (POST) http://{server}/modelA/update/{id} . And when the request returns success response, update the local database.
2. Same as method 1. But differ the server request timing. At the touchupinside event of the button in the tableViewCell, only update the local database and set the dirty tag. And when user dismiss the tableView, at the ViewWillDisappear, request server to update dirty items using this REST API : (POST) http://{server}modelA/updates . In this way, we can reduce the number of server request to one and save network resource.

Which way is more suitable? I think that these task is common to networing app but can't find any advises.

Comment: Two is much safer. You also have to account for the situation in which there is no network access or it fails. So you will need to check for network access and remaining dirty local records.

Comment: @johnelemans Of course. Actually, because of that additional burden, I ask this question. If someone knows about client-server data synchronize guide or book, it's appreciate to inform me.